# I want to make program that UPDATE if data already exist else it will INSERT

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

I want to make a program for Warehouse Management System in my company using Visual Studio and Ms Access. As i describe on title, i want to make If Function where it will INSERT data if the data is new and UPDATE if data already Exist.

Because i'm new in programming, i follow this guys instruction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q19OXha1jDw
and make a Class so i can make query in access.Execquery function.

```
Private Sub UpdateDb(KimapValue As String, PoValue As String, LocValue As String, QtyRecValue As String, DateVal As String, PemasokVal As String)
    Access.AddParam("@KiValue", KimapValue)
    Access.AddParam("@PoVal", PoValue)
    Access.AddParam("@LocVal", LocValue)
    Access.AddParam("@QtyValue", QtyRecValue)
    Access.AddParam("@DateValue", DateVal)
    Access.AddParam("@PasokValue", PemasokVal)

    Access.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM dbWarehouse
                       CASE WHEN NoPo = @PoVal AND Kimap = @KiValue AND Lokasi = @LocVal THEN
                        UPDATE dbWarehouse SET Quantity = Quantity + @QtyValue WHERE NoPo = @PoVal AND Lokasi = @LocVal
                       ELSE
                        INSERT INTO dbWarehouse (Kimap, NoPo, Lokasi, Quantity, TanggalMasuk, Pemasok) VALUES (
                        @KiValue, @QtyValue, @LocVal, @PoVal, @DateValue, @PasokValue)
                        END ")

End Sub

Private Sub ReceiveBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReceiveBTN.Click
    UpdateDb(KimapTB.Text, NopoTB.Text, LokasiTB.Text, QtyTB.Text, TanggalMasukDTP.Value.ToString, PemasokTB.Text)

    MsgBox("Data Receive sudah dimasukkan, silahkan letakkan barang di " + LokasiTB.Text + " !")
End Sub
```

I expect the output will UPDATE if NoPo and Kimap and Lokasi is TRUE else it will INSERT

ps : i'm Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Search on topic 'UPSERT' query. What is your question? What issue are you having?